# How to load jQuery dependent HTML with external JavaScript files to JavaFx WebView

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, webview, javafx

How can I load JavaScript to a JavaFx Webview after `$(document).ready(function()` *ie. after the webview loads and without waiting for events like `onButtonClick` action, for example?*

The answer to this would answer my main question, **How to add jQuery into a webview?**.

I've been trying to make the following work but I've been unsuccessful at integrating other similar solutions online onto my problem.

The HTML file I'd like to add onto a webview is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ]
        });

    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

    #calendar {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I've been trying to do so far:

```
public class WebViewSample extends Application {

    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(), 750, 500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("WebViewSample/fullcalendar-1.6.4/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

    class Browser extends Region {

        final WebView browser = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

        public Browser() {
            //apply the styles
            getStyleClass().add("browser");
            // load the web page
            webEngine.load("WebViewSample/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/default.html");
            //add the web view to the scene
            getChildren().add(browser);

        }

        private Node createSpacer() {
            Region spacer = new Region();
            HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
            return spacer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            double w = getWidth();
            double h = getHeight();
            layoutInArea(browser, 0, 0, w, h, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
            return 750;
        }

        @Override
        protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
            return 500;
        }
    }
```

All I get from this is a blank white window, instead of something like the jQuery calendar plugin ***[FullCalender](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/selectable.html)*** being drawn on the window.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/> 
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="fullcalendar.css" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        //events:"%EVENT_URL%",
        allDaySlot: false,
        header:
        {
             left: 'today prev next',
             center: 'title',
             right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
        defaultView:'agendaDay',
        firstHour:'9',
        minTime:'8:00',
        weekends: true    
   });   

});
</script>
```